# What universities (especially in the USA) prohibit or restrict duplicate advanced degrees?

Tags: graduate-school, united-states, university, degree, second-degree

For example, University of California - Berkeley [says](https://grad.berkeley.edu/policy/admissions-policy/#b13-evaluation-of-applicants)

> The Graduate Council views academic degrees as evidence of broad
>   research training, not as vocational training certificates; therefore,
>   applicants who already have academic graduate degrees should be able
>   to take up new subject matter on a serious level without undertaking a
>   graduate program, unless the fields are completely dissimilar.

and [says](https://grad.berkeley.edu/policy/degrees-policy/#f43-duplication-of-graduate-degrees)

> Students may enroll for a second academic or professional master’s degree if the second degree is in an unrelated field.

What are some other universities that prohibit or have restrictions on the duplication of advanced degrees?

Answer (score 3):

This is more of a statement of how resources are allocated than a strict prohibition. It is a statement of "may enroll", rather than one of "may not enroll". I think admissions committees at a lot of places take a similar view, even without a formal statement. "Why do you think you need a second math masters?"

The available slots and money are limited most places and committees generally want them to be be used to expand the pool of educated folks.

So, I think that any numerical answer will be misleading. And any listing would be equally misleading.

But the statement is useful as guidance to those who would want to apply when it would be unlikely that the committee would accept them.